# R Markdown word sections don't work after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: macos, ms-word, r-markdown, macos-catalina, sections

I have upgraded my Mac to Catalina. Since the upgrade, my RMarkdown files, knit in word format, with or whithout Reference_docx don't work.

I obtain this : #Part 1 instead of 1) Part 1.

Anyone have the solution to my problem?